# reorganizar try/catch/finally

Tags: c#, .net, archivo, try-catch

Tengo este código:

```
try{//...código
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create);
    ....//código
    fs.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex){throw ex;}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es meter el `fs.Close()` dentro de un finally, porque si hay errores, pues cierras el `stream`. Parece lógico, y razonable, cerrar los recursos en el bloque de `finally` y es lo que se recomienda.

Problema, el `stream` se crea en el `try`, así que en el `finally` no se reconoce, porque está fuera de ámbito.

Al principio pensé en crear `fs` fuera del `try` y luego inicializar valores, pero ahí tengo otro problema que es que no se admite el constructor por defecto, el que tiene 0 parámetros.

Luego pensé en mover la línea donde creo `fs` a fuera del `try`, pero pensé que si estoy creando un archivo para escribir esto debería y tiene lógica estar dentro del `try`.

Vamos, que cómo cierro los recursos en el bloque `finally` en caso de que haya algún error y me meta en el `catch`?
Estoy usando **.NET standard 2.0** y el código se usa en múltiples aplicaciones así que no estoy por la labor de hacer un gran cambio por lo que pueda pasar.

Son varios streams los que manejo en el código

Comment: No termino de entender el problema. Puedes crear el FileStream fuera del try `FileStream fs=null;`  e inicializarlo dentro. Por otro lado, te recomendaría usar FileStream en un bloque `using` para que haga dispose de los recursos correctamente.

Comment: o sea, crear el fileStream  con FileStream fs sin usar el constructor? yo intenté var fs = new FileStream() fs; y no me dejó, pero veo que es perfecto, no se me había ocurrido

Comment: Lo he intentado y me sale 'Use of unassigned local variable 'fs' error en el finally al hacer fs.Close();

Comment: Tienes que asignar `null`: `FileStream fs=null;`. Pero como dije, la forma de hacerlo es lo que te indica @Paperbirdmaster en su respuesta :

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Lo que quiero hacer es meter el `fs.Close()` dentro de un finally, porque si hay errores, pues cierras el stream.

No es necesario un `try`/`catch`/`finally` para eso. Utiliza `using`:

```
try { // … código

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create)) {
        … // código
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){ … }
```

Los recursos creados con esa cláusula serán eliminados implícitamente al abandonar el ámbito, ya sea por finalizar la función como por excepción.

Comment: Con `using` ni siquiera sería necesario un `try/catch`(de hecho, el compllador  [genera internamente un try/finally](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)), a no ser que necesites capturar la excepcion para algo.

Comment: Podría ser necesario un `try`/`catch` para excepciones no manejadas por el *stream*.

Comment: como he dicho, el código se usa en múltiples sitios de los cuales no tengo control, así que tengo que capturar el error por si acaso, y relanzarlo otra vez por si hay otras partes del código que sí hacen algo con ello

Comment: @Iria [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions) te explica la forma correcta de capturar excepciones en objetos _disposables_, y coincide exactamente con esta respuesta

Comment: resuelto, al final he usado lo siguiente using (...){using(...){using(...){...}...}...} porque lidiaba con varios streams, supongo que no hay manera de usar un único using, intenté && y ',' pero me daba error, así que los dejo encapsulados, muchas gracias!

Comment: @Iria echa un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1329765/579895) para tener un código mas legible

Comment: gracias, he conseguido poner dos using juntos, ya que se necesitan ciertas variables para la creación de uno de ellos que son intermedias y ciertas comprobaciones antes de crear el segundo stream, y además no todos los stream son del mismo tipo

Answer (score -1):

deberías crearla fuera del try, y luego en el finally comprobar que no sea null para no tener excepcion de querer ejecutar un metodo sobre un objeto null.

```
FileStream fs;

try{//...código
   fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create);
    ....//código

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
throw ex;}
finaly
{
   if(fs != null)
      fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: son varios streams que dependen unos de otros, asi que en algun momento habra alguno nulo

Comment: Hola no especificaste que son varios stream y si hay alguno null no hay problema porque no va a intentar cerrar algo null y no tendras excepcion.  No tienes motivos para calificar negativo si tu pregunta esta mal formulada.